# Find multiline HTML comment with regex?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have this html structure I am trying to find and replace, using Sublime Text 2.

### Question

How can I select the entire thing in the code sample:

`<!-- FOOTER --> ... everything in between ... <!-- /FOOTER -->`

### Code sample

```
<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- col #1 -->
            <div class="dark col-md-3">

            </div>
            <!-- /col #1 -->

            <!-- col #2 -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">

            </div>
            <!-- /col #2 -->

            <!-- col #3 -->
            <div class="spaced col-md-3 col-sm-4">

            </div>
            <!-- /col #3 -->

        </div>

    </div>

    <hr />

</footer>
<!-- /FOOTER -->
```

### What I've tried

I've tried this but doesn't work of course:

```
.*<!-- FOOTER -->(.*?)<!-- /FOOTER -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify it to a singleline regex, and escape the backslash:

```
(?s).*<!-- FOOTER -->(.*?)<!-- \/FOOTER -->
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/vN7vH2/1)!

Comment: brilliant! thanks for your help! http://regex101.com/ is excellent. I'll start using it for everything regex. great way to learn.

Comment: I didn't know about the inline modifier thx (and the website is great!).
Btw, you don't actually need the `.*` in front of the FOOTER.
And yes, your issue was that `.` does not include the '\n' character. The inline modifier works, you could also have included it in your capturing group.

Comment: @Unihedron Sure, your answer is perfect. It's better than including the newline character. I just thought I'ld point it out, because I feel that in some cases, it would be easier to add this char in the regex, as opposed to play with the inline modifier. I'll definitely use your solution though.